# About React, Suspense, lazyLoad and preloading/rendering elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I am studying the `<Suspense>` and `React.lazy()` concepts, and I would like to better understand what happens in order to add some logic into an existing app.

Let's start with the definitions:

> The React.lazy function lets you **render** a dynamic import as a regular component.

(**render** highlighted by me)

and

> If the module containing the OtherComponent is not yet **loaded** by the time MyComponent renders, we must show some fallback content while we’re waiting for it to load[...]

(**loaded** highlighted by me)

Now, the `Suspense` definition uses the term *load*, `lazy()` uses *render*.

Let's add some code to the concept.

```
const ComponentOne = React.lazy(() => import("./ComponentOne"));
const ComponentTwo = React.lazy(() => import("./ComponentTwo"));

function BigBang() {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<SplashScreen/>}>
            <section>
                <ComponentOne/>
                <ComponentTwo/>
            </section>
        </Suspense>
    );
}
```

Fine. The idea is that we are lazy-loading ComponentOne and ComponentTwo.
While this process is not over, we will display SplashScreen.

**THE QUESTION**
Now, let's assume that I have some import to some local images into ComponentOne and ComponentTwo (I will add the code only for one, let's assume there is something similar for the other one):

```
import avatar from "../../img/avatar.svg";
import logo from "../../img/logo.svg";

export default class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("ComponentOne@componentDidMount");
    }

    render() {
        console.log("ComponentOne@render");
        return (
            <div style={{display: 'none'}}>
                <img src={avatar}/>
                <img src={logo}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now it should be clear what I would like to ask:

Does the SplashScreen disappear when ALL the imports are loaded? In other terms, when the SplashScreen disappear, can I assume that all the images in the ComponentOne and ComponentTwo are already loaded?

This is the main question.

A secondary question (that seems related to me, but if it's not I can open another thread) is: if the answer to the previous question is "NO", what is the best strategy to be sure that the images/fonts/"api response"/"other resources" are loaded before rendering, possibly maintaining the  logic because of an already existent flow? Direct `fetch()` to resources is not supported at the moment.

Comment: You are not performing any dynamic loading here. Those are regular imports This is only mean to be used with Webpack's `import()` function. In the sample you have given, the import statements are removed and transformed into urls by the `file-loader` The browser loads those urls, if you want React to load anything you have to use `React.lazy(() => import('/path/to/file'))` but this only works for components not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Suspense` waits for the dynamically imported component file (lets say `0.js`) to get fetched. 
Now as soon as `0.js` is loaded and starts parsing, `Suspense` stops showing `SplashScreen` and delegates control the your component. Whatever happens next is not lazy loading. It would just be like what would happen if you did a static import.

In your case, the two images would be loaded only after the `SplashScreen` goes away. Now if you want to preload / lazy load the images there are several ways to go ahead with that.

1) If you are using webpack, you can use `url-loader` to inline the images as `data-uri`. But beware, that this might increase your bundle size and also you lose out on browser caching of images which are usually static.

2) For svgs, you can use the `inline-react-svg` babel plugin which will convert the svg's to react component so that its part of your bundle (`0.js`). But it also has the same tradeoff mentioned above.

Hence preloading images has its own tradeoffs. There might be better alternatives such as lazy loading which can be done by easily and also React HOC can be got from several third party libaries.